# Is it possible to control the overall size of off heap memory

Tags: java

I know there are options to control the size of on heap size, which are `-Xmx, -Xms`,

But I wonder whether there are option to control the overall size of off heap size.

I know that `DirectMemory, JNI, Thread...` all use off heap, I would like to know whether there are options to control the overall size of off heap size.

So that, I could control the memory usage of the whole Java Process, which is off heap memory + off heap memory.